# Configure alerts for TTS API

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring

Is there a way to configure alerts for TTS API error rate?

The documentation explain in details how to configure monitoring/alerting for Google Cloud Platform, but not the APIs and Services. APIs and services dashboard provides a lot of graphs, but I cannot seem to find an option to configure an alert.

Thank you!